# ¿Cuál es el origen de la frase "al pan, pan, y al vino, vino"?

Tags: etimología, modismos

Creo que la expresión quiere decir que algo fue dicho con claridad, pero ¿de dónde viene la expresión?  Es decir: ¿a qué se refiere originalmente? ¿Por qué pan y vino, precisamente?

Comment: Existe en italiano también.

Comment: En portugués, una persona es pan, pan, queso, queso (pão, pão, queijo, queijo) cuando dice siempre lo que piensa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La forma habitual es "al pan, pan, y al vino, vino" ([fuente](http://dle.rae.es/pan)). Se refiere a que debemos llamarle "pan" al pan, y "vino" al vino. Es decir, llamar a cada cosa por su nombre.

En otras palabras, podemos pensar que hay un verbo elíptico: "(Llamar) al pan, pan y al vino, vino".

El origen es seguramente relativo a la liturgia católica tan popular en España en tiempos antiguos, donde el pan y el vino eran los elementos básicos de la comunión.

Answer (score 12):

En la liturgia católica, el pan representa "el cuerpo de Cristo" y el vino "la sangre de Cristo".

**Llamar al pan "pan" y al vino "vino" significa utilizar un lenguaje llano y directo, sin metáforas ni simbolismos.**

Answer (score 3):

Pan y vino son los dos elementos de la comunión.  Bien puede ser que esto sea el origen del dicho.

Answer (score 1):

Esta expresión viene de los tiempos de Lutero, Zunglio y Calvino que discutían sobre la eucaristía si el pan y el vino era sustancial o  Transubstanciación y Zunglio reflexiona al tema diciendo que el Pan es pan y el vino es vino en otras palabras solo son símbolos del cuerpo y sangre de Jesús.

Answer (score 0):

Es frase popularizada por los republicanos ateos en la Guerra Civil.

> Debemos llamar al Pan, Pan, no el cuerpo de Cristo y al vino, vino, no la sangre de Cristo

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Normalmente las respuestas deben ir documentadas para verificar lo que estás afirmando. En este caso, yo diría que la frase ya era popular mucho antes de la guerra civil. Por ejemplo: _"No os maravilléis, amigos míos, que estos mis criados son tan torpes y rústicos de ingenio, que no saben decir sino al pan, pan, y al vino, vino."_ Esta frase fue escrita en el siglo XVI por Juan de Timoneda.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, @Charlie, pero a mi me parece que las otras respuestas, incluso la aceptada, tienen exactamente el mismo problema: dan un origen que no está documentado en ninguna fuente fiable, como si el pan y el vino fueran exclusivos de la liturgia católica, cuando ya aparecen, por ejemplo, en la epopeya de [*Gilgamesh*](https://books.google.es/books?id=v5-NBCfndfQC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=pan+vino&source=bl&ots=yM9FEb_srQ&sig=ACfU3U26lvkIKQ-wb2_vq2oR4ps5JxuCwg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBwfGbxIvgAhUPDGMBHZIAAgQQ6AEwBXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=pan%20vino&f=false).

Comment: @Charo puedes dar una respuesta con los detalles que citas en tu commentario

Comment: @mdewey: No creo que pueda dar una respuesta porque realmente no sé cuál es el origen de esta expresión. Lo único que quería decir con mi comentario es que la simbología del pan y el vino es mucho más antigua que el cristianismo. Me sorprende que se vote e incluso se acepten respuestas inventadas, no documentadas. De hecho, en [Italian.SE](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10200) se hizo la misma pregunta y en cuanto apareció una respuesta parecida a las que aquí han recibido votos positivos, enseguida fue votada negativamente y criticada en comentarios: se acabó borrando. Sigue sin respuest